# User defined exception: Exception vs ApplicationException

Tags: exception, defined

I want to implement user defined exception in my project. And I got so many articles in internet.

I have to create a custom class and that will be inherit from `Exception class`.
Ex: `public class EmployeeListNotFoundException: Exception{ }`

I got so many articles who are saying custom class should inherit from `ApplicationException class`.

But according to msdn site it will be inherit from Exception class. See link
`[Userdefined exception][1]`.

Then what should I use `ApplicationException` or `Exception class`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Before the release of **.NET 3.0**, **Microsoft** advised to derive custom exceptions from the `ApplicationException class`. However, it was found that this practice did not add any value, so the current recommendation is to derive custom exceptions from the `Exception class`.

Comment: Then ApplicationException class is now obsolete, right?

Comment: Obsolete, in the sense that it's use is deprecated. It will however continue to exist in the framework.